# How to upload multiple images using WP rest API to media?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, rest-api

I'm using JWT Authentication for WP REST API plugin and WP REST API Controller plugin

Take this [rest api](https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ads/24282) for example, it's an api for [this post](https://jokerleb.com/ads/bmw-x6-v8-407-hp/), and here's [the media](https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=24282)

I understand everything about it, except how to upload media?

The `id` is created automatically, do I have to save it and hit the media endpoint? Or is there a simpler way? Is there any example?

Comment: Have you tried multiple requests? I'm not sure that bulk uploading is possible in a single request, the non-REST uploaders don't even do that

Comment: @TomJNowell I haven't, tomorrow I will and will let you know